# Is there a way to wait for the result of an Observable called within another Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, electron, rxjs6, angular8

I am currently experimenting with building a little app for helping my local roleplay group. Amongst the tools they wanted was a scriptable randomizer so that they could build dice roll tables. Unfortunately, I've hit a bit of a brick wall with regards to needing to recursively call a function with an Observable in it.

I've had a look through a few different questions on here and Reddit covering how to get results from Observables or wait for it to resolve but all the solutions I've tried either are invalid code in this context or the parent call doesn't wait for the child to resolve. This includes using map, switchMap and async/await. I'm left wondering if I'm wrong to be using an Observable for the file load on this.

Here's the full context in case the short example misses somehting: https://github.com/Acaeris/draconika/blob/rolltable/src/app/providers/table.service.ts

In short:

```js
@Injectable()
export class TableService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get(tableId: string): Observable<RollCollection> {
    return this.http.get<RollCollection>('assets/tables/' + tableId + '.json')
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  // Roll a result from a given table or sub entry.
  roll(tableId: string, entryKey: string) {
    return this.get(tableId).pipe(
      map(data => {
        output = data[entryKey];
        parts = this.findParts(output);

        parts.forEach((part: string) => {
          if (part[1].includes('.')) {
            const splitPart = part[1].split('.');

            // Roll refers to an entry in another table.
            // This needs to finish before the return...
            this.roll(splitPart[0], splitPart[1]).toPromise()
              .then(rollOutput => output = output.replace(part[0], rollOutput));

          } else {
            // Process rolls for current file.
          }
        });

        return output;
      }
    );
  }

  private findParts(entry: string) {
    const regex = /\[([a-zA-Z.]*)\]/g;
    const parts: string[] = [];
    let m;

    do {
      m = regex.exec(entry);

      if (m) {
        parts.push(m);
      }
    } while (m);

    return parts;
  }
}
```

This is currently called in a component like so:

```js
this.tableService.roll('heirloom').subscribe(
  data => this.output.push(data),
  error => console.log(error)
);
```

The heirloom.json table has some rolls that result in calls to [name.format] which should then roll the 'format' entry of the name.json file.

What I expect it to do is roll the result and replace the [name.format] part of the string from the heirloom roll.

```js
this.tableService.roll('name', 'format').subscribe(
  data => this.output.push(data),
  error => console.log(error)
);
```

^ This will successfully return a generated name, and indeed the internal roll will also result in a name but it applies too late for the output and so the component receives the result before it's finished.

What I'm currently getting is: "The heirloom is a helmet that once belonged to [name.format]" instead of "The heirloom is a helmet that once belonged to Lady Amberline Dawnstrider"